# What is the connect string in oracle 12c when creating sample db?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I was creating sample database using the mksample.sql script from Oracle.

One of the parameters it asked is the "connect string". What is this?

PLSQL Output after running the mksample.sql script:

```
specify connect string as parameter 12:
Enter value for 12:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script doesn't match the documentation here (there are only 11 parameters):
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/scripts.htm#COMSC00018

but if you open the mksample.sql file and look for something like

```
PROMPT specify connect string as parameter 12:
```

it should be followed with something that looks something like this:

```
DEFINE connect_string = &12
```

From there do a search on the variable in the DEFINE statement (I'm just guessing it's "connect_string", you might find something else) prefixed with "&&". Using my example, I'd search for &&connect_string and see where it's used. I'm guessing it's used in one of this statements:

```
CONNECT system/&&password_system@&&connect_string
```

If you need more info, just ask.